# Read span value in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular7

```
<span class="headmain" style="cursor:pointer" (click)="modalshow(ratingImage,el.name+i,el)"  >
hello</span>
```

How to get the value from span element in similar to formControlName?
Span element is in a form tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ViewChild / ElementRef.

HTML:

```
<span #mySpan (click)="handleClick()">
  Hallo from span.
</span>
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("mySpan", { static: false }) mySpanRef: ElementRef;

  public handleClick(): void {
    const spanValue = this.mySpanRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    console.log("Span-Value: ", spanValue);
  }
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ydmwh5)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, iam using form builder group to read the value from input with formcontrolname attribute.This span element is in ngforloop so in similar to that  how to get dynamic element from span element.                                                                                   return this.fb.group({
    ScoutName: [''],
    Rating:[''],
    Advice: [''],                                                                                                                         
             })

Comment: Ok. Then we need more code to help you. Otherwise it is just guessing.